# Can't make a system with the info given

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve a problem using Gauss. First I need to make a system with the info my teacher gave to me but I can't figure out the 3rd one.

A book store has 3 differents types of leather: normal, hard and luxury. The number of normal is double the luxury. So I have the first one: $2x=z$

We know they make 300 a day. So the second one is: $x+y+z=300$

But then the information left I have is the minutes each one takes to do: normal 3 minutes, hard 5 minutes and luxury 8 minutes. We also know the machinery is working all day making that 1440 minutes.

The question is how many of each type is used daily. What am I missing?

I normally know how to do these one but this is a new for me.

Comment: Presumably the machinery can only make one at a time, so 3x+5y+8z=1440.

Comment: I thought about that, but I tried with that and it didn't seem to work

Comment: Because in the end we are using different type of things in the same system

Comment: Maybe you meant the first equation to be x=2z, assuming x is the number of normal ones.